# mazda dealer thinks i have changed the CVN code in my car

Tags: mazda, computer, cvn

My mazda dealer thinks I've chiptuned my car even though I didn't. Help what to do. Here's their message:
I could again find no DTC and as there was also no manual data started with checking the software. In the software there is a CVN could that is kind of signature ehen the calibration file is written, in this case someone changed the file (did chip tuning) so the CVN code does not match with the original one that belongs to the file. Those files for chip tuning change also the threshold for DTC´s and therefore we possible do not see any DTC. So please ask the customer to go this company to start troubleshooting

Comment: Please edit your question title so it is English and edit the body we can understand the question. From what I can make out the garage mechanic has told you to go back to the company who did the chip upgrade to work on a solution ie as you, or some other, has messed around with it - they don't want to work on it any more. For them to accept to work on it, you may have to set it back to standard...

Comment: Did you buy this car new or used? What model and what motor are we talking about?

Comment: Yes a brand new Mazda CX3 model 2015, but bought in 2017